# How do I show that M is a two-dimensional submanifold?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I have the following problem:

> Let $M=\{(a,b,c,d):ac=b^2, bd=c^3,ad=bc,abcd\neq 0\}$. Show that M is a two dimensional submanifold.

So we had the following definition about submanifolds:

Def: $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is submanifold of dimension k if for all $a\in M$ one of the following three equivalent points holds:

1. For each $a\in M$ there exists an open neighbourhood $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a diffeomorphismen $\phi:U\rightarrow V$ where V is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$\phi(U\cap M)=V\cap(\mathbb{R}^k\times \{0\})$$
2. For each $a\in M$ there exists an open Neighbourhood $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a submersion $F:U\rightarrow \mathbb{r}^{n-k}$ at a such that $$U\cap M=U\cap\{F=0\}$$
3. For each $a\in M$ there exists an open $O\subset M$ and and open $O'\subset \mathbb{R}^k$ and a homeomorphism $\phi:O'\rightarrow O$ such that $\phi$ is a immersion at $\phi^{-1}(a)$ and $O=\phi^{-1}(O)$

But I somhow don't understand how to work with them, could someone help me please? I am at this exercise for too long.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this?

Comment: I have really no idea since I don't understand the definition/theorems. I thought that maybe with this exercise it will get easier to understand it but it doesn't work. Could you maybe explain me what the definition tells me and how to work with it because in the lecture our Prof haven't comment this definition, it was like a side remark although we haven't had this topic before

Comment: I would be very thankful if you could help me.

Comment: You need only to check one of 1, 2, 3, and 2 is the easiest to use here. If you don't understand the definitions, start with some simpler examples. Do you know why $\{(a, b, c) : a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1\}$ is a $2$-dimensional submanifold?

Comment: so in your example I can define $f(a,b,c)=a^2+b^2+c^2-1$, so clearly $M=\{f=0\}$ then $Df=(2a\,\,\,\,\,2b\,\,\,\,\,2c)$. Now we need to check if $f$ is a submersion right? But we remark that since $(0,0,0)\notin M$ $Df\neq 0$ therefore it has rank 1, so maximal rank. Then we have a submanifold of dimension 3-1. Right? But how do I need to check that $U\cap M=U\cap \{f=0\}?

Comment: In this case you can just use $U = \mathbb R^3\setminus \{(0,0,0)\}$.

Comment: Sorry do you speak about your exercise or mine? But why do I need this additional statement?

Comment: Mine. ${}{}{}{}{}$. In your exercise, just do the same. What is $F$ in this situation?

Comment: I think in my case $F:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ with $F(a,b,c,d)=(ac-b^2,bd-c^2,ad-bc)$ but then something with the dimension wouldn't work? Or does I see this wrong

Comment: Is my F correct?

Comment: Please help, I'm really really lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition $abcd \neq 0$ implies that $a, b, c, d$ are all non-zero. In particular,

$$ d =\frac{bc}{a}$$
Plug it into $bd = c^3$, we have
$$ \frac{b^2 c}{a} = c^3\Rightarrow ac^2 = b^2$$
Since $ac = b^2$, it implies that $c = 1$. Thus $a = b^2, d = 1/b$. Hence

$$M = \{ (b^2, b, 1, b^{-1}) : b\in \mathbb R\setminus \{0\}\}$$

and indeed $M$ is one-dimensional.

With that in mind, one consider

$$ F : U \to \mathbb R^3, F(a, b, c, d) = (a-b^2, c-1, d-b^{-1}),$$
where $U = \{ (a, b, c, d) : abcd\neq 0\}$. It is clear that $F^{-1}(0,0,0) = M$ and

$$DF = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2b & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & b^{-2} & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
clearly has full rank (consider the first, third and fourth column). Thus definition 2, $M$ is a one dimensional submanifold in $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: but here we don't have a F?

Comment: Please see the edit, @Wave

Comment: But M should be a two dimensional submanifold so they wrote this in the exercise

Comment: @Wave Your question is wrong. It IS a one dimensional submanifold as I (and other user) showed.

Comment: So you mean that my Prof wrote us a wrong question? Oh noo this is horrible

Comment: It is a one dimensional submanifold. I don't know why your prof claimed otherwise. @Wave

Comment: Yes I think thats the point why I was so confused because in my coputations my Df had rank 3 so the submanifold had dimension 4-3=1 and I always thought that it has to be 2

Comment: @Wave In the future, please also show your work in the post, so that we know exactly where you are confused....

Comment: yes I will do this thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can show that the four equations are equaivalent to $a =\frac{1}{d^2}, b = \frac{1}{d}, c = 1$. Let $\Omega = \mathbb{R} - \{0 \}$ and define a map $F : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^4$ by

$$F(d) = \bigg( \frac{1}{d^2}, \frac{1}{d}, 1, d \bigg).$$

$F$ is clearly a diffeomorphism of $\Omega$ onto $M$.

Comment: okey but $DF=(\frac{-2}{d^3}, \frac{-1}{d^2},0,1)$ and thus it has rank 1 right? But then we have a manifold of rank 4-1=3 and not two?

Comment: $F$ here is not the $F$ you need in 2. @Wave

Comment: $F$ here corresponds to $\phi$ in your definition 1.

Comment: Sorry shouldn't that be my third definition?